# Directory index full, is this fsck result OK?

Tags: centos, filesystems, centos6, directory, fsck

I found these in my **/var/log/messages**:

```
kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device md2): ext4_dx_add_entry: Directory index full!
kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device md2): ext4_dx_add_entry: Directory index full!
kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device md2): ext4_dx_add_entry: Directory index full!
```

I rebooted the system with a rescue system/image and without mounting the drives, I ran fsck like this: `fsck -f /dev/md1` and then `fsck -f /dev/md2`

This is the **result**:

```
root@rescue ~ # fsck -f /dev/md1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/md1: 39/131072 files (28.2% non-contiguous), 47998/524224 blocks
root@rescue ~ # fsck -f /dev/md2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/md2: 33915958/121020416 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 119497991/484052208 blocks
root@rescue ~ #
```

Does this fsck result look OK ? It was first time I used it. 
Is there anything to worry about because of those `index full` errors ?

Edit: This is the output of command `df -i`

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md2             121020416 33929994 87090422   29% /
tmpfs                4109010       2 4109008    1% /dev/shm
/dev/md1              131072      39  131033    1% /boot
```

Comment: What OS is this? Are you running fsck on the live mounts? Can you paste the output of `df -i` ?

Comment: @deppfx I edited my question and included the `df -i` output, I assume that 29% is what interests you? I knew I had many files in one folder and I kept an eye on this value, it was always around 29%. I didn't ran the `fsck` directly on the machine, I booted in a separate "rescue" OS.

Comment: Try `fsck -D` by this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/644071/ubuntu-12-04-ext4-ext4-dx-add-entry2006-directory-index-full